# Iterating and validating through a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a pandas DataFrame called **'heat'** consisting of **2 columns, A and B**

Column A cells hold string values of : 'High' 'Low' and 'Central'.

What I want to achieve is iterate through the dataframe and do the following checks:

```
If string at column A ends with 'gh', fill column B with 'Yes'

If string at column A ends with 'ow', fill column B with 'No'

If string at column A ends with 'al', fill column B with 'Maybe'
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `map`:

```
heat["B"] = heat["A"].str[-2:].map({"gh": "Yes", "ow": "No", "al": "Maybe"})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
One more question. If I have a different string value in column A than those mentioned in your mapping dictionary, it will replace any value present in column B with NaN. Do you know how I can avoid that?

Comment: Use `replace` instead of `map`. This will give you the last two characters of the string if it's not "gh", "ow" or "al". Separately, please do not ask follow-up questions in the comments. Make a new post if you need to.